# Infinispan singleFileStore cache restartability

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, jboss-cache

I am using infinispan 6.0.1 release, I have configured it to use SingleFileStore as loader

Configuration is as below

```
<namedCache name="MyCache">
 <persistence passivation="true">
    <singleFile fetchPersistentState="true"
                 ignoreModifications="false"
                 purgeOnStartup="false" maxEntries="5000">
     </singleFile>
  </persistence>
```

My question is, will this cache survive JVM restarts?
I mean lets say my cache is holding {n} entries and my jvm goes down.
When JVM starts again will my cache initialized with {n} entries?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

With passivation, the entry is EITHER in memory (activated) OR in cache store (passivated). Therefore, no, it won't.

Comment: so its not at all possible to have recover from jvm restarts? Can we utilize shutdown hook..?

Comment: If you talk about shutdown hooks, you probably consider grateful ones - after calling cacheManager.stop() etc. In that case, yes, entries are passivated into disk correctly. I had rather in my mind those non-grateful such as JVM crash or machine going out of power.

Answer (score 2):

With passivation enabled, my understanding is, that everything only present in memory will persisted during shutdown. However, I cannot find proof in the InfiniSpan documentation now.

Anyway, keep in mind that the SingeFileStore is not a robust implementation. The stored value will only survive, if you do a correct shutdown.

Comment: The proof is only in source code, never trust documentation too much :) but you're right. When the cache manager is stopping PassivationManagerImpl.passivateAll() is called (as this is annotated by @Stop).